# Using a BI texture in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, modifiers

I'm using a displacement modifier on a mesh like this:

[image]

Is is possible to get this displacement texture into cycles? I'd like the displacement height to influence the colour of the material.

Comment: AFAIK it isn't possible to get the *exact same* texture the displace modifier uses into Cycles.  But you could use Cycles' true displacement feature instead of a displacement modifier.  Is that an option?

Comment: I should have included this in my question, but I'm stacking a few displacements on top of each other (displacing along updated normals along the chain). I doubt I can make this work, but I'm giving it a try.